# The CC email will not send using PEAR

Tags: php, email, pear

I have read the similar posts about this problem but can't quite get my head around what I am doing wrong here. The 'To' email is received ok.

However, I can not get the **'CC'** email to send when using the following script.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Require Pear Mail Packages 
require_once ("Mail.php"); 
require_once ("Mail/mime.php");
require_once ("Mail/mail.php");

$crlf = "\n"; 
$from = "Company <admin@example.com>";
$to =  $purchasersName . "<" . $purchasersEmail . ">";
$cc = "Company <admin@example.com>";
$subject = "Company Order Confirmation";

$host = "localhost";
$port = "25";
$username = "the username";
$password = "the password";

$hdrs = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Cc' => $cc,
'Subject' => $subject);

$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
$mime->setHTMLBody($mailBody);
$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$smtp =& Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'port' => $port,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $hdrs, $body);
```

Comment: Not an expert either so not sure. However the `$subject` is included in the `$hdrs` array and appears correctly in the sent email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comment is in the pear docs on this page

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

(If you want other options, you could try http://swiftmailer.org, I have used that on lots of projects now)

> Note by: arminfrey@gmail.com 2007-07-08 05:13 UTC In order to send
>   e-mail to cc or bcc with smtp you have to list the cc e-mail address
>   both as a recipient (which decides where the e-mail is sent) and in
>   the cc header, which tells the mail client how to display it.
>
> Here is the code I use:
>
> $to = 'to@example.com'; $cc = 'cc@example.com';
>
> $recipients = $to.", ".$cc;
>
> $headers['From'] = 'from@example.com'; $headers['To'] = $to;
>   $headers['Subject'] = 'Test message'; $headers['Cc'] =
>   'cc@example.com'; $headers['Reply-To'] = 'from@example.com';
>
> $send = $mail->send($recipients, $headers, $body);